# Keep Sub menu open on child page, change if hover on another item, then return

Tags: jquery, menu

Although there are plenty of similar questions I can't find anything with the particular case I'm looking for.

I have a wordpress site with sub-navigation that shows on hover and being animated with HoverIntent.  This is fine and works great, but I'd like the sub-menu to stay active if on one of it's child pages - BUT - if I hover over any of the other parent items I want that sub-menu to show - if nothing is clicked I want it to revert back to showing the original sub-menu.

Here is my menu:

```
<div class="menu-main-navigation-container">
<ul id="menu-main-navigation" class="menu">

<li id="menu-item-90" class="menu-item-90"><a href="http://sitename.com/services/">Services</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-123" class="menu-item-123"><a href="http://sitename.com/services/design/">Desgign</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-109" class="menu-item-109"><a href="http://sitename.com/services/seo/">SEO</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-110" class="menu-item-110"><a href="http://sitename.com/services/development/">Development</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li id="menu-item-89" class="menu-item-89"><a href="http://sitename.com/portfolio/">Portfolio</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-113" class="menu-item-113"><a href="http://sitename.com/portfolio/web/">Web</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-108" class="menu-item-108"><a href="http://sitename.com/portfolio/print/">Print</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

And my current jQuery code:

```
// hover intent
var config = {
sensitivity: 3, // number = sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)
interval: 10, // number = milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval
over: doOpen, // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)
timeout: 500, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut
out: doClose // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)
};

function doOpen() {
    jQuery(this).addClass("hover");
    jQuery('ul:first',this).fadeIn();
}
function doClose() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("hover");
    jQuery('ul:first',this).fadeOut();
}
jQuery("#menu-main-navigation li").hoverIntent(config);
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've created a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/bldoron/zcJEu/
Can you explain what's not working for you? When I'm on a child the submenu doesn't close. Is it not what you'ld expect?

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle that's awesome - to clarify the sub-menu is showing on hover, but I meant I'd like it to stay active while on that page - show the other sub menus if their parents are hovered on but revert back to the current sub menu if no hovering is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case: What you need is to know which page you are on.
Say we are on 'web' page.
Add:
`<div id='page_web'></div>`
In the beginning of the page.

Then, In JS:

```
if ($('#page_web').length > 0){
  jQuery("#menu-main-navigation li:first").hoverIntent(config);
} else {  
  jQuery("#menu-main-navigation li").hoverIntent(config);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
}
```

This is of course just a suggestion, and there are other ways to do this.
I've updated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bldoron/zcJEu/1/). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I'll give this method a try and report back!